# Can't collect information at the same time from two different depth using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to get the `name` and `reputation` using `get_names()` function from it's landing page and then click on the link of different posts to reach the inner page in order to parse `title` using `get_additional_info()` function from there.

> All of the information that I'm trying to parse are avaialabe in landing page as well as inner page. Moreover, they are not dynamic, so selenium is definitely overkill. ***However, my intention is to make use of selenium to scrape information simultaneously from two different depth.***

In the script below If I comment out `name` and `rep` lines, I can see that the script can perform clicks on the links of landing pages and parse the `title`s from inner pages flawlessly.

However, when I run the script as it is, I get `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` error which points at this `name = item.find_element_by_css_selector()` line.

***How can I get rid of this error and make it run flawlessly complying with the logic I've already implemented?***

I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

lead_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_names():
    driver.get(lead_url)
    for count, item in enumerate(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".summary")))):
        usableList = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".summary .question-hyperlink")))

        name = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".user-details > a").text
        rep = item.find_element_by_css_selector("span.reputation-score").text

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",usableList[count])
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1 > a.question-hyperlink")))

        title = get_additional_info()
        print(name,rep,title)

        driver.back()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(usableList[count]))

def get_additional_info():
    title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1 > a.question-hyperlink"))).text
    return title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)
    get_names()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping broadly with your design pattern...Don't work off `item`. Use `count` to index into list of elements pulled from current `page_source` e.g.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".user-details > a")[count].text
```

Py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

lead_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_names():
    driver.get(lead_url)
    for count, item in enumerate(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".summary")))):
        usableList = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".summary .question-hyperlink")))

        name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".user-details > a")[count].text
        rep = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.reputation-score")[count].text

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",usableList[count])
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1 > a.question-hyperlink")))

        title = get_additional_info()
        print(name,rep,title)

        driver.back()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(usableList[count]))

def get_additional_info():
    title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1 > a.question-hyperlink"))).text
    return title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)
    get_names()
```

---

[image]